# Javascript Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've inherited someone else's web site and I'm trying to resolve why a javascript-based rollover menu doesn't work in anything but IE (compatability mode enabled).

The code, via an included menu.js:

```
function goMenu(m,n){
 if(n){
  showMenu(m);
 }else{
  hideMenu(m,n);
 }
}

function showMenu(m) {
   for(i=0;i<6;i++){
      if (i!=m){
         hideMenu(i);
      }
   }

   if(document.all){
      eval('document.all.menu'+m+'.style.visibility="visible"');
   }else{
      eval('document.menuSpan.document.menu'+m+'.visibility="show"');
   }
}

function hideMenu(m) {
   if(document.all){
      eval('document.all.menu'+m+'.style.visibility="hidden"');
   }else{
      eval('document.menuSpan.document.menu'+m+'.visibility="hide"');
   }
}
```

And then the code in the HTML file is basic

```
<SPAN ID="menu0" ONMOUSEOUT="goMenu(0,0);" ONMOUSEOVER="goMenu(0,1);">
     <LAYER ONMOUSEOUT="goMenu(0,0);">
     ...
     </LAYER>
</SPAN>
```

This worked fine for years in IE (latest version needs compatability mode enabled), and never worked in Firefox or Chrome that I am aware of.  Now the business owners want me to make it work in all browsers. I'm not really a javascript person so I'm not sure what the errors from the javascript console mean:

```
From IE:
Unable to get property 'document' of undefined or null reference

From Chrome:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
```

I have tried tweaking the code in the menu.js but to no avail. Would someone with any Javascript experience be able to tell me what would make this code work with the latest browsers, if anything?

Comment: Why in the world would you use `eval()`  here rather than just using the direct code?

Comment: `document.menuSpan.document` you are trying to reference `document` from `menuSpan`

Comment: Holy wow.... it's not just the eval - why are there layers here? Is that for supporting netscape o_0?

Comment: @jfriend00 To be fair, the OP said it was inherited code.  This code, though, should inherit a spot in the trash... rewriting it will be the only savior.

Comment: OP, I feel so sorry for you. No one should inherit this sort of code, no one. The best thing you can do is probably read "JavaScript: The Good Parts" or something similar. This code is __full of anti patterns__ you want to avoid when coding in JavaScript. It also has a bunch of deprecated stuff that's supposed to accomodate 1998 browsers.

Comment: +1 for sheer sympathy

Comment: @JeremyMiller - yeah, I saw the word "inherited", but I agree with you - this code needs to go in the trash and be rewritten with techniques considered appropriate for today and today's browsers.

Comment: @jfriend00 Was using `eval` ever a good way to go? lol.

Comment: @JeremyMiller - no `eval()` was never a good way to go, but there was a very long time ago when code like `if (document.all)` was a standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess it's from one of the `document.menuSpan.document` operations. `document.menuSpan` is probably undefined. It's not part of any API.